# Generate download link based on HTTP POST response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a method in C# which basically generates a string in form of a CSV file like following:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("ExportFolder")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public string ExportFolder(int? folderId)
        {
            if (folderId != null)
            {
                using (var ctx = new myContextEntities())
                {
                    var uid = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);

                    var itemsToExport = ctx.Items.Where(y => y.MyListId == folderId && y.UserId == uid).ToList();
                    var sw = new StringWriter();
                    sw.WriteLine("\"Title1\",\"Title2 \",\"Title3\",\"Title4\",\"Title5\"");
                    foreach (var item in itemsToExport)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\"",
                            item.Title1,
                            item.Title2,
                            item.Title3,
                            item.Title4,
                            item.Title5
                            ));
                    }
                    return sw.ToString();
                }
            }
            return "error";
        }
```

Basically this should now be a ready "CSV" file available for download once the POST is done.

The jQuery part looks like following:

```
   $(document).on("click", ".exportFolder", function () {
        $.post("/ItemManagement/ExportFolder", { __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', '#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm').val(), folderId: $(this).attr("ID") }).done(function (data) {

        // Now I should here download the file... 

        });
    });
```

But I'm not sure now how to trigger the download part? Can someone help me out?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a placeholder element which will contain anchor link to call controller action for downloading the file like this one:

```
<div id="dlink">
</div>
```

Then you can store the generated string inside `TempData` or `Session` variable and return CSV file name as JSON response:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ExportFolder")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult ExportFolder(int? folderId)
{
    if (folderId != null)
    {
        using (var ctx = new myContextEntities())
        {
                var uid = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);

                var itemsToExport = ctx.Items.Where(y => y.MyListId == folderId && y.UserId == uid).ToList();
                var sw = new StringWriter();
                sw.WriteLine("\"Title1\",\"Title2 \",\"Title3\",\"Title4\",\"Title5\"");
                foreach (var item in itemsToExport)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\"",
                        item.Title1,
                        item.Title2,
                        item.Title3,
                        item.Title4,
                        item.Title5
                        ));
                }
                TempData["Contents"] = sw.ToString();
                return Json("FileName");
        }
    }
    return Json("error");
}
```

Afterwards, create a controller action with GET method to return `FileResult` which triggers file download when anchor link was clicked, according to `TempData`/`Session` content:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadCsv(string fileName)
{
    string csv = TempData["Contents"] as string;

    string fileNameWithExt = fileName + ".csv";

    // check if the CSV content exists
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csv))
    {
        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", fileNameWithExt);
    }
    else
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

And finally create download link by appending anchor tag into `done()` function of `jQuery.post()`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".exportFolder", function () {
    $.post("/ItemManagement/ExportFolder", { __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', '#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm').val(), folderId: $(this).attr("ID") }).done(function (data) {
        if (data == "error") {
            alert(data); // show error message
        }
        else {
            var placeholder = $('#dlink');

            // remove existing anchor links inside placeholder
            placeholder.empty();

            // generate new anchor link                
            $('<a href="@Url.Action("DownloadCsv", "ControllerName")' + '&fileName=' + data + '">Click here to download CSV file</a>').appendTo(placeholder);
        }
    });
});
```

Note that you cannot download CSV file directly from `$.post()` response because AJAX response intended to stay on the same page, therefore another controller action with GET method is necessary to provide download functionality which triggered from generated anchor link.

**PS:** The placeholder element here is just an example, you can modify it depending on your needs.

References:

[Download CSV file in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnetxp.com/download-csv-file-asp-net-mvc/)

[Creating an anchor in a div](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/creating-an-anchor-in-a-div)